# "Open with" defaults to previusly used application

Tags: 20.04, gnome, visual-studio-code

When I right click desktop file with `.code-workspace` extension (saved VS code worskapce) and select "Open With", VS code opens automatically instead of showing list of options.
The default application in 'Right click -> properties ->"Open with"' for this file is set to `Text Editor`.

A few days ago everything was working as expected, so it's most likely related to recent update. It's not exactly a huge problem, since VS code is what you normally open these files with, but I'm curious why this could be happening.

Edit: I just checked, and this happens only with files located on Desktop, and only with `.code-workspace` extension files.